# How to send integers in query parameters in nodejs Express service

Tags: node.js, express

I have a nodejs express web server running on my box. I want to send a get request along with query parameters. Is there any way to find type of each query parameter like int,bool,string. The query parameters key value is not know to me. I interpret as a json object of key value pairs at server side.

Comment: you could send a json object in the get request like `http://domain.com?json={"key":intValue}` and then parse the value of query param json into a JSON object with `JSON.parse(req.json)`

Answer (score 46):

You can't, as HTTP has no notion of types: everything is a string, including querystring parameters.

What you'll need to do is to use the [`req.query` object](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query) and manually transform the strings into integers using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
req.query.someProperty = parseInt(req.query.someProperty);
```

Comment: is there any other way like custom headers or something where i can send the query parameters as json object.

Comment: We ran into similar requirement where JSON needs to be sent in a get request.  We ended up using POST instead... Yes, POST sounds odd for doing a GET but that's one way to get around it.

Answer (score 14):

You can also try

```
var someProperty = (+req.query.someProperty);
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned by Paul Mougel, http query and path variables are strings. However, these can be intercepted and modified before being handled. I do it like this:

```
var convertMembershipTypeToInt = function (req, res, next) {
  req.params.membershipType = parseInt(req.params.membershipType);
  next();
};
```

before:

```
router.get('/api/:membershipType(\\d+)/', api.membershipType);
```

after:

```
router.get('/api/:membershipType(\\d+)/', convertMembershipTypeToInt, api.membershipType);
```

In this case, req.params.membershipType is converted from a string to an integer. Note the regex to ensure that only integers are passed to the converter.

Comment: I think this solution throws a typescript error since req.params is defined as a `map: [key: string]: string;` and thus you can't assign an integer to the string value.

I was really excited about it though as it would be reusable for every `get` endpoint that accepts an `id` as a path param

Comment: With TypeScript you don't get an error if you declare your request parameter as `req: Request<{}, {}, {}, { id: number }>` inside your function.

Answer (score 1):

```
let originalType = JSON.parse(req.query.someproperty);
```

In HTTP, querystring parameters are treated as string whether you have originally sent say `[0,1]` or `5` or `"hello"`.
So we have to parse it using json parsing.

Answer (score 1):

This have been answered a long ago but there's a workaround for parsing query params as strings to their proper types using 3rd party library [express-query-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-query-parser)

```
// without this parser
req.query = {a: 'null', b: 'true', c: {d: 'false', e: '3.14'}}

// with this parser
req.query = {a: null, b: true, c: {d: false, e: 3.14}}
```

Answer (score -1):

//You can use like that

let { page_number } : any =  req.query;

```
    page_number = +page_number;
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this will be of any help to those who read this, but I like to use arrow functions to keep my code clean. Since all I do is change one variable it should only take one line of code:

```
module.exports = function(repo){
    
  router.route('/:id',
  (req, res, next) => { req.params.id = parseInt(req.params.id); next(); })
    .get(repo.getById)
    .delete(repo.deleteById)
    .put(repo.updateById);
}
```

Comment: Be careful not to "clean" your code at the expense of readability.