# Parse numbers from query strings with bodyParser.urlencoded() in express.js

Tags: express, body-parser

In the front end, I use jQuery to send a GET request like this:

```
$.get('/api', {foo:123, bar:'123'), callback);
```

according to jQuery doc, the 2nd parameter is a plain object that will be converted into query string of the GET request.

In my node express back end, I use body-parser like this:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query) // req.query should be the {foo:123, bar:'123'} I sent
});
```

However, `req.query` turns out to become `{foo:'123', bar: '123'}` where all the numbers were converted to strings. How can I revert to the exact same object I sent from front end?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send integers in query parameters in nodejs Express service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355876/how-to-send-integers-in-query-parameters-in-nodejs-express-service)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP understands that everything is a string same goes for query string parameters. In short, it is not possible. Just convert your data to integer using parseInt()

example

```
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  console.log(parseInt(req.query.bar)) // req.query should be the {foo:123, bar:'123'} I sent
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this snippet which parses the convertible ones:

```
query = Object.entries(req.query).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = isNaN(+value) ? value : +value
  return acc
},{})
```