# How do i receive post data at server same as client post data format using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I have a post data in the format below

```
{"geoJSON":{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-102.038635,36.800488],[-94.567716,36.800488],[-96.149793,43.381098],[-104.060178,43.508721]]}}}
```

Expecting the same format on the server but received the format below

```
{"geoJSON":{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[["-102.038635","36.800488"],["-94.567716","36.800488"],["-96.149793","43.381098"],["-104.060178","43.508721"]]}}}
```

You can see the difference in `coordinates` property. Double quotes are added to each value in server received `coordinates` array. How can I get the `coordinates` array same as client post data?

My application configured with expressJS and using body-parser. Any additional settings required to fix the problem?

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more context. Your object does look like valid JSON, so that is not the problem.

Comment: You won't have that problem if you are sending data in the POST format you describe. (Possibly your client-side code is encoding that data in URL encoded format, but you've indicated otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, from [@bumblebeen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49526398/3651221), HTTP understands everything as a string and as such converts everything to a string. It's up to you to parse it using `Number.parseInt`

Also, it is irrelevant but express now ships with it's own body parser which you can use. So, rather than calling `bodyParser.json`, you simply call `express.json`

### Edit

Per the comment stated, you could have a function called `parseCoordinates`

```
function parseCoordinates(coordinates) {
     return coordinates.map(inner => {
         return Array.isArray(inner) ? inner.map(elem => parseFloat(elem)) : parseFloat(inner);
     });
}
```

Comment: here `coordinates` property is a multidimensional array. Can you give an easy way to parse those values same as client post data?

Comment: The values are not integers.

Comment: You just have to change from `Number.parseInt` to `Number.parseFloat`

Answer (score 1):

Assum I have

```
var payload = {"geoJSON":{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-102.038635,36.800488],[-94.567716,36.800488],[-96.149793,43.381098],[-104.060178,43.508721]]}}}
```

Using JSON.stringify(payload) to stringify this before send server.

```
payload = JSON.stringify(payload)
// after this code then sending payload to server
```

In the server using JSON.parse(payload) to use this

```
// server nodejs
var receivedContent = JSON.parse(payload)
// then you can using receivedContent with format you want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{"geoJSON":{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-102.038635,36.800488],[-94.567716,36.800488],[-96.149793,43.381098],[-104.060178,43.508721]]}}}
```

The above is actually a JavaScript Object.

```
{"geoJSON":{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[["-102.038635","36.800488"],["-94.567716","36.800488"],["-96.149793","43.381098"],["-104.060178","43.508721"]]}}}
```

where as the above is actually a JSON.

As one of the answer suggested, whenever you send data to server, everything in the payload will automatically be converted to strings. You should cast the values as numbers.

Also, I don't think any parse would be able to do it and you should write your own code for that. The reason I say it is because, the parser would never know if the original value was a string sent by the client or was actually a number since all the keys and values will become strings.