# Default values for route parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, express, parameters, routes

I am trying to simplify some of my code in javascript. 2 route parameters can be passed in, which are then multiplied together.

I want to have a default value for the parameters if nothing gets passed in e.g firstnum and secondnum are both 4. Currently I have set up my code as three separate functions for each scenario (0, 1 or 2 parameters being passed).
Am I also able to restrict the parameters (e.g they can only enter numbers)?

For example, this takes 2 parameters:

```
app.get('/multi/:num1/:num2', function (request, response) {
 var firstnum = request.params.num1;   
 var secondnum = request.params.num2;
 var multiply = firstnum * secondnum
response.write(multiply)
response.send();
```

Taking 1 parameter:

```
app.get('/multi/:num1 function (request, response) {
var firstnum = request.params.num1;   
 var secondnum = 4
 var multiply = firstnum * secondnum
response.write(multiply)
response.send();
```

Comment: Write a separate handler function, like `function multiply (res, firstnum, secondnum) {...}` in which you send back the reply. Now write the individual route handlers and call `multiply(...)` from inside them.

Comment: Sorry I'm not too sure what you mean, are you able to give a brief example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex for the url :

```
multi/:num1?/:num2?
```

which makes your request params optional. So it should be :

```
app.get('/multi/:num1?/:num2?', function (request, response) {
   var firstnum = request.params.num1 ? request.params.num1:4;   
   var secondnum = request.params.num2 ? request.params.num2:4;
   var multiply = firstnum * secondnum
   response.write(multiply)
   response.send();
}
```

What we are doing here is we are checking if `request.params.num1` and `request.params.num2` are not `undefined` via a ternary expression. If they are defined, we use their value. Otherwise we set it to `4` which is your default.

Read more in the [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html):

> Express uses path-to-regexp for matching the route paths; see the path-to-regexp documentation for all the possibilities in defining route paths. Express Route Tester is a handy tool for testing basic Express routes, although it does not support pattern matching.

For the last part of your question, please refer to the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355876/how-to-send-integers-in-query-parameters-in-nodejs-express-service)