# How to stop number being converted to string in xmlHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, express, xmlhttprequest

How do I stop a number being converted to a string when adding an element to a JSON file on a server using xmlHttpRequest?

The following code updates my .json file with the element but the number (var importance) is a string by the time it arrives at the server... and I can't work out why.

This is where I format my input data and create the xmlHttpRequest.. (script.js):

```
   btnSubmit.onclick = submitTask;

function submitTask() {
    inputTask = document.querySelector('#task');
    inputImportance = document.querySelector('#importance');
    var task = inputTask.value;
    var importance = Number(inputImportance.value);
    console.log("User Input: ",task, importance);

    //Setup XML HTTP Request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', api_url_add +'/'+ task +'/'+ importance, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    //Receive response from server.
    xhr.onload = function() {  
        response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        console.log(response);
    }

    xhr.send();
}
```

And this is the server side code (server.js):

```
// ADD task to the list (task, importance)
app.post('/add/:task/:importance?', addTask);

function addTask(request, response) {
    var data = request.params;
    console.log('Submitted to server:','\n', data);
    var task = data.task;
    var importance = Number(data.importance);
    var reply;
    
    if (!importance) {
        var reply = {
            msg: "Importance value is required."
        }

    } else {            
        var element = data;              
        tasks['taskList'].push(element);
   
        fs.writeFile('tasks.json', JSON.stringify(tasks, null, 2), function(err){
            console.log('all done')
        })

        response.send(reply);
    }

}
```

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: this is your answer?https://stackoverflow.com/a/34933025/5677187

Comment: Thanks. I understand this in principle but am struggling to implement it.. From this, I understand that all HttpRequests are strings, and so, I need to intercept the string before I process it at the server to convert my target parameter (in this case 'importance') from a string to an integer. I  presume I would intercept the HttpRequest at the top of the 'addTask' function in my server code (so the function that intercepts is executed before the rest of the addTask function)... any help with what that looks like would be really appreciated.

Comment: why you did optional importance ? then you validate the existance of it?